# Chemiluminescence vs. Bioluminescence

Tags: photochemistry

Luminescence in general, is the term of emission of light from specific substances/objects. Chemiluminescence is the emission of light *due to chemical reactions*. Bioluminescence on the other hand is the emission light from *living/biological organisms* such as insects ( this is of course the way I understood them ), but I'm a little bit confused because what is the cause that makes insects emmit light? Doesn't that also have to do with chemical reactions but inside living organisms ?

Just a clear explanation of the difference  between these two terms  would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: Simply searching the title of your question into Google yields a multitude of sources that can explain the difference between the two, including [this one](http://www.comm-tec.com/Library/Tutorials/CTD/Chemiluminescence%20and%20Bioluminescence%20Measurements%20.pdf). Try Google first before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't that also have to do with chemical reactions but inside living organisms?

Exactly! That's why there is **one** scientific society for **both** phenomena: [ISBC - International Society for Bioluminescence and Chemiluminescence](http://www.isbc-society.org) ;-)

The thermal reactions, that lead to an excited species which eventually emits a photon are quite similar. From a reactive compound, typically called a *luciferine*, a four-membered ring, often a dioxetanone is formed. This decarboxylates and gives rise to a molecule in an electronically excited state. In reality, the decarboxylation is often not just a spontaneous process but requires an activator. W. J. Baader at IQUSP in Sao Paulo, Brazil has examined that in great detail.

The *luciferines* can be quite different compounds, such as

- diaryloxalates (these are used in glow sticks, where the diferent colours come from diferent fluorphores that absorb the initial photon and emit at different wavelength)
- benzothiazole derivatives (firefly)
- triazine derivatives (marine organisms)