# What is the difference between the following terms: Incandescence, luminescence, fluorescence, phosphorescence, chemiluminescence and bioluminescence?

Tags: energy, terminology, photochemistry

What are the differences between  incandescence, luminescence, fluorescence, phosphorescence, chemiluminescence, bioluminescence?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31039/chemiluminescence-vs-bioluminescence/31044#31044

Comment: The page on wikipedia gives a rather nice summary on the different types of luminescence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminescence 
Incandescence is different from the others in that it is caused by heat. Again,  there's a wiki page for that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/colours-and-transition-metals/8100#8100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was a '*catchy*' question ;)

First a broad division into : Incandescence and Luminescence.

**Incandescence** is the emission of light from a body that is heated until it glows.

**Luminescence** is the emission of light by a substance for any reason *other* than rise in its temperature.

Now the following come under Luminescence:

If the *cause* of the excitation is due to *photons* striking atoms, the associated emission of light is called **photoluminescence**. If it is due to *electrons*, then the emission of light is referred to as **electroluminescence**.

If the luminescence results from a *chemical reaction*, it is **chemiluminescence**. A form of chemiluminescence, where the emission of light is due to a chemical reaction occurring *in vivo*, then it's called **bioluminescence**.

If the luminescence persists significantly (according to my Oxford Science dictionary, a period of time *greater* than 10 nanoseconds would be "significant") after the exciting cause has been removed, it is called **phosphorescence**. If it fails to persist for longer than 10 nanoseconds, then it's called **fluorescence**.

EDIT- @KlausWarzecha answered the Fluorescence-Phosphorescence conundrum better in his answer here : [What happens to electrons in metal complexes after excitation by visible light?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/colours-and-transition-metals/8100#8100)

Quoting from his answer:

> There are however cases, in which the initially formed excited singlet state species first relaxes to its lowest vibrational mode and the emits a photon to reach the ground state.
>
> $$\ce{S_1 -> S_0 + h\nu_{f}}$$
>
> This deactivation via radiation is known as **fluorescence**. Fluorescence lifetimes are typically rather short (in the ns range) and the emitted photon has a lower energy than the absorbed one.

and on phosphorescence,

> In other cases, the excited singlet state undergoes a change in the spin multiplicity (**Intersystem crossing**) to a triplet state.
>
> $$\ce{S_1 ->[ISC] T_1}$$
>
> These excited triplet states are usually much longer-lived. When they eventually deactivate via emission of a photon, this process is known as **phosphorescence**.
>
> **$$\ce{T_1 -> S_0 + h\nu_{p}}$$**

Note that the way I 'defined' fluorescence and phosphorescence has been greatly oversimplified (and possibly *wrong*), but it should suffice for your purpose. ;)